# Redirecting %20 Based URL to Non %20 based URL

Tags: uri, redirection

I have a URL suppose http:www.domain.com/somepath%20%20

When i open the above URL, it exist with both URLs http:www.domain.com/somepath and http:www.domain.com/somepath%20%20

I would like to know how can I redirect %20 based URL to Non %20 based URL

P.S I have made this page using Panels.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the alias on the page to see if two trailing spaces exist. That's where the %20 typically comes from. %20 is an HTML encoded space character.

In the meantime, you can handle multiple links to one page using [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect).

Best to get that in so your site is not penalized by search engines.